# Meteor.userId vs Meteor.userId()

Tags: meteor, userid

I have a short piece of code, like so, to update the name in my user's profile:

`Meteor.users.update({_id: Meteor.userId()}, {$set:{"profile.name": name}});`

When I'm working locally, I can use `Meteor.userId` or `Meteor.userId()` without issue. However, when I deploy to Modulus, I run into issues. If I don't have the operator on it, it will do the initial $set, but no more. If I user the operators, it behaves as I would expect.

Why is this? I assume that I shouldn't have been using this without the operator to begin with, but is there a reason why it worked at all?

Comment: Meteor.userId() and Meteor.userId cannot be the same. Meteor.userId returns a function Meteor.userId() returns a string. i think you are talking about this.userId which is available only inside publications and Meteor.methods.

Comment: Nope, strange as it may be, I was using Meteor.userId, server-side and not in a publication.

Comment: Probably you're setting the _id to the string representation of the `Meteor.userId` function.  Something like `"function() { ... }"`.  Which will successfully set the value, but that's not what you want. Can you open your mongo console and look through a few documents to see what the _id fields look like?  `meteor mongo` from the CL

Comment: @pahan, just to be clear, you write *Meteor.userId returns a function*, which is incorrect. Functions **return** values (possibly), while `Meteor.userId` **stores** (is) a function.

Answer (score 6):

Have a look in the [documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_users)

- The function `Meteor.userId()` is available "Anywhere but publish functions"
- The variable `this.userId` is available "Anywhere" (which explicitly is also called out for the Server side Publish function).

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same issue with Meteor.userId() when trying to get a unit testing with mocha to work.

A simple fix is to go to `tasks.js` and replace `Meteor.userId()` with `this.userId` which 
is to use the `this` context of the function.