# Meteor - Why should I use this.userId over Meteor.userId() whenever possible?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, meteor-accounts, ddp

Judging from [this comment](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/2734#issuecomment-58969491) by David Glasser in the GitHub issues:

> `this.userId` is the primary API and `Meteor.userId()` is syntactic sugar for users new to JavaScript who might not understand the details of successfully using this yet

It seems like we should use `this.userId` whenever possible (such as inside a method function, where you can use both), and only use `Meteor.userId()` inside publish functions. If this assumption is correct, ***why***?

(Referring to the relevant bits of the code would also be helpful, I can't seem to find it)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Meteor.userId vs Meteor.userId()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24320754/meteor-userid-vs-meteor-userid)

Comment: @CollinD That question is with regards to `Meteor.userId` vs `Meteor.userId()`. This question is with regards to `this.userId` vs `Meteor.userId()`

Comment: There is an answer that seems relevant. It specifically references your question. Sorry if it isn't.

Comment: @CollinD Thanks for trying to provide a relevant link, but in a method function, where you can use both `this.userId` or `Meteor.userId()`, why choose one over the other?

Comment: Consider performance as a factor. That is the main reason for using this.userId rather than Meteor.userId

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your question seems to conflate `Meteor.userId()` and `Meteor.user()`. The body of the question seems to be asking about the former while the subject line is asking about the latter. I'll try to address both.

1. On the server, within a publish function, calling either `Meteor.userId()` or `Meteor.user()` will [cause an error](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/cf6d7f109b23ab989d6649201678e1a9cabd510b/packages/accounts-base/accounts_server.js#L80). Instead, use `this.userId` or `Meteor.users.findOne(this.userId)`, respectively. However, note that the publish function is only called when a client subscribes. If you want the publication to change when the user record changes, you'll need to `observe()` the cursor returned by `Meteor.users.find(this.userId)` and take appropriate action when the record changes.
2. On the server, while a method call is being processed, `Meteor.userId()` and `Meteor.user()` will correspond to the ID of the calling user and their record, respectively. However, be aware that calls to `Meteor.user()` will result in a DB query because they are [essentially equivalent to `Meteor.users.findOne(Meteor.userId())`](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/cf6d7f109b23ab989d6649201678e1a9cabd510b/packages/accounts-base/accounts_common.js#L52).

   Directly within a method call, you can also use `this.userId` instead of `Meteor.userId()`, but you are unlikely to see a significant performance difference. When the server receives the method call, it [runs your method implementation with the user's ID (and some other info)](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/a23cc0249217715cd160112a47c2fff6f5becf89/packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js#L706) stored in a particular [slot](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/ee1cba5b9746f756bbb9e9bc6f859b2c11e9bc9d/packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js#L16) on the fiber. `Meteor.userId()` just retrieves the ID from the slot on the current fiber. That should be fast.

   It's generally easier to refactor code that uses `Meteor.userId()` than `this.userId` because you can't use `this.userId` outside of the method body (e.g. `this` won't have a 'userId' property within a function you call from the method body) and you can't use `this.userId` on the client.
3. On the client, `Meteor.userId()` and `Meteor.user()` will not throw errors and `this.userId` will not work. Calls to `Meteor.user()` are [essentially equivalent to `Meteor.users.findOne(Meteor.userId())`](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/cf6d7f109b23ab989d6649201678e1a9cabd510b/packages/accounts-base/accounts_common.js#L52), but since this corresponds to a mini-mongo DB query, performance probably won't be a concern. However, for security reasons the object returned by `Meteor.user()` may be incomplete (especially if the `autopublish` package is not installed).

Comment: Thanks for the spot, I did mean `Meteor.userId()` and have corrected the question title. Everything in your answer is quite clear and confirms what I have been reading. Would it be possible for you to expand a little on "Since Meteor.userId() will work deeper in the call stack"? In your previous comment, you said "Meteor.userId() doesn't query the DB or consume any significant extra resources." - then what does it do? I haven't been able to find this piece of code in the source code.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, although I can't claim to understand the code you linked to, I do understand a little more how `Meteor.userId()` works now. Also thanks for giving an alternative viewpoint to the comment in the question, that using `Meteor.userId()` may be better because you can port the same code elsewhere, maybe on the client. Thanks again for you answer.

Answer (score 1):

Simply speaking, Meteor.userId() queries the DB everytime you use it. In client side ( logically ), it looks fine - since we have minimongo.

In server side, using Meteor.userId(), consumes extra resources on SERVER, which, at times is undesired.

Now, this.userId is more over like a session variable m ie it will have a value only when there is a userid attached with the current session. And hence,using 'this' reference wont go and fetch the database everytime, but rather than that it used the active session userId.

Consider performance as a factor. That is the main reason for using this.userId rather than Meteor.userId

Comment: Calling Meteor.user or Meteor.userId from publish functions cause an exception. ie, these are available any where in the server except publish functions, while this.userid is available ANYWHERE. Also, it is clear that Meteor.user Meteor.userId etc fetches the user object from the mongo (via Accounts object ) - See https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/accounts-base/accounts_common.js#L222

Comment: `Meteor.userId()` doesn't query the DB or consume any significant extra resources. However, on the server, `Meteor.user()` does.