# Meteor method create insert hook and bind userId on the server

Tags: meteor, methods, hook

I implemented a hook function, where I attach some `createdAt` and `updatedAt` fields to the `doc` that is inserted to a collection. I can attach this to any collection like this:

```js
export const insertHook = function (doc) {
    try {
        const user = Meteor.user();
        doc.createdBy = user && user._id ? user._id : null;
        doc.createdAt = new Date().getTime();
    } catch (e) {
        console.err(e);
    }
};
```

Attaching the hook to the collection is basically passing it via a third option in the constructor:

```js
class HookedCollection extends Mongo.Collection {

    constructor(name, options, hooks={}) {
        super(name, options);
        this.insertHook = hooks.insertHook;
    }

    insert(doc, callback) {
        if (this.insertHook && Meteor.isServer)
            this.insertHook.call(this, doc);
    }
}

export const MyDocs = new HookedCollection("mydocs", {}, {insertHook});
```

In a Meteor method I just do a normal insert:

```js
Meteor.methods({
    insertDoc:function(doc) {
        //check doc...
        return MyDocs.insert(doc);
    }
});
```

Which creates basically the following error:

```
Error: Meteor.userId can only be invoked in method calls or publications.
```

I tried several ways of `bind` but always ended up in this error. Is there really no way at all to bind the userId to the function?

Comment: You're referencing `Meteor.user()` but you don't need the whole user object, just the `_id`. Try `this.userId` or `Meteor.userId()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Meteor docs](https://docs.meteor.com/api/accounts.html#Meteor-userId) `Meteor.userId()` is available anywhere but publish functions (Server side Publish function).

You aren't using `Meteor.userId()` directly in the method but in a callback (see discussion [in this github issue](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/2221)). You can pass the `userId` information to your callback function as a parameter from the method, for example:

```js
// Using Meteor.userId()
Meteor.methods({
    insertDoc:function(doc) {
        //check doc...
        return MyDocs.insert(doc, Meteor.userId());
    }
});

// Or using this.userId
Meteor.methods({
    insertDoc:function(doc) {
        //check doc...
        return MyDocs.insert(doc, this.userId());
    }
});
```

As a general rule use `Meteor.userId()` in the client (that queries the database) and `this.userId` in the server. More information in this other question [Meteor - Why should I use this.userId over Meteor.userId() whenever possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32800211/meteor-why-should-i-use-this-userid-over-meteor-userid-whenever-possible) and in [Meteor forums](https://forums.meteor.com/t/difference-between-this-userid-and-meteor-userid/2767)